# Error while reading multiple rows from mysql in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

Looking at the approach on Internet to read multiple rows from mysql db in bash I am doing following :

```
i=0
while read relation_id
do
  echo "Record $(( i++ )) $relation_id"
done < <(mysql -u$db_user -p$db_password -h$db_host -D$db_name -se "SELECT id where connection_id=$id")
```

But unfortunately I am getting following error :

```
temp.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
temp.sh: line 11: `done < <(mysql -u$db_user -p$db_password -h$db_host -D$db_name -se "SELECT id where connection_id=$id")'
```

Please help me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, I am using the same query to do other things.

Comment: All the referred variables defined properly above the command?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space **done < <(mysql** here. It should be << not < <

Comment: Already tried that it gives `temp.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('` error

Comment: please recheck the code, i pointed out the obvious mistake only, but it seems your query is also not correct.  it should be something like, `mysql -u (username) -p (password) -se "SELECT id from (database).(table) where relation_id= (id)"`